# How to show User current Location - GPS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I followed the following [tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/mapkit-example-in-iphone/) to embed Maps to my application.

Later on I have added a button, and when the user clicks on it, I will show the user their current location; here's my code:

```
-(void)showUserLocation {
self.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
}
```

But, when the map is pointed to Russia, and my user location is in London how can I move the map to my userlocation ?

**In detail:** 
When I click the button `Show User current location`, it draws the blue dot on the map. But it doesn't take me to that point. If the map is pointed to Russia, and my user location is in London, how can I move the map to point to my user location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this MKMapView method: [setCenterCoordinate:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setCenterCoordinate%3aanimated%3a)

```
MKUserLocation *location = self.mapView.userLocation;
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longutde) animated:YES];
```

This should be preferably be implemented using this MKMapViewDelegate method: [mapView:didUpdateUserLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView%3adidUpdateUserLocation%3a)